# Trying to play media to a Sony TV using DLNA

Tags: upnp

Sitting on kubuntu, there is alas no 'Sharing' in Settings. So I guessed I had to add software. I tried minidlna, which works but is limited and cumbersome (configuration, startup, permissions), and most of all: not all formats will play on the Sony TV.

So tried rygel, which should contain renderers. However, it doesn't seem to do anything. When I start it, it comes up with some

```
(rygel:68800): RygelCore-WARNING **: 18:49:44.545: Failed to load user configuration from file “/home/me/.config/rygel.conf”: No such file or directory
Rygel-Message: 18:49:44.546: Rygel v0.40.3 starting…
RygelCore-Message: 18:49:44.700: New plugin “MediaExport” available
MediaExport-Message: 18:49:44.811: “file:///home/me/Videos” harvested
MediaExport-Message: 18:49:44.811: rygel-media-export-harvesting-task.vala:309: Harvesting of file:///home/me/Videos done in 0,037277
```

And so forth. That's all. Nothing else. nmap shows no open port for dlna.

What next?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, answer to my own question. Just starting rygel from the command line, made actually available the media as desired available in the network.

I only didn't see anything, because somehow, the technology used seems to be working differently: Starting the minidlna wold have brought up some port eight-thousand-something. Here, at starting rygel nothing such happens:

```
$ nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-05-10 16:01 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp open  ipp
```

and yet, the clients can see the files and play them.